# How does encapsulation actually work?

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces, class-design, encapsulation

I made the following diagram to show a typical separation of concerns as typically taught -

[image]

Here `ClassA` indirectly uses `ClassB` via the `ISomeInterface`, of course ensuring it doesn't know `ClassB` exists, only the methods within the interface, which `ClassB` implements. All the information I can find on this separation of concerns ends here, and nowhere can I find out how `classA` can actually use the interface without coupling itself to `ClassB`.

You can't of course instantiate nothing but an interface, an interface has no implementation or functionality itself. So how does `ClassA` use the interface?

There are only two ways currently that come to mind -

1) `ClassA` does the following:

```
ISomeInterface obj = new ClassB();
```

Here we can make sure we're not calling any members of `ClassB` directly, only interface members. The problem though is that `ClassB` has leaked through to `ClassA` via the instantiation.

2) `ClassA` relies upon the interface only, delegating this responsibility of passing the `classB` object elsewhere, via having the following constructor:

```
class ClassA {
        ISomeInterface obj;

        ClassA(ISomeInterface obj) {
            this.obj = obj;
        }
    }
```

This of course completely decouples `ClassA` from `ClassB`, however all it does is "pass the buck" elsewhere since *someone, somewhere*, must instantiate an implementation of ISomeInterface (such as `ClassB`) and pass it as an object to `ClassA`.

All the tutorials and explanations I can find leave out this last crucial detail. Who exactly is responsible for doing this last crucial thing? It has to happen somewhere. And is the thing that does this now coupling itself to both `ClassA` & `ClassB`?

Comment: In your constructor example if you pass a ClassB to ClassA's constructor that's where it happens. Otherwise it will be a null pointer

Comment: @VictorS Yes but who is responsible for passing ClassB into ClassA's constructor? Where does this actually happen?

Comment: Wherever you initialize ClassA with a ClassB instance passed as its constructor parameter of course

Comment: ClassB does not actually leak to ClassA for that to happen. The interface means ClassB has a contract to support the methods defined in it. Meaning any calls to an ISomeInterface method for any class implementing it must be valid for the said class, so your implementation does not need to know the rest of ClassB for you to pass it an instance of it

Comment: Ah ok, so it's fine for a higher layer to know that lower layers exist, and reference them, but only for the purposes of instantiating some object within them via the agreed interface?

Comment: In your example the higher layers do not 'know' ClassB is a ClassB. The compiler sees a class that implements your interface, and allows it to be passed as instances of that interface type. Any class with a field of that interface type cannot access the rest of that class, only the parts defined in the interface

Comment: Ok it's just that I was thinking if I later removed classB and changed it for instance to classC, I'd need to edit the source code now of the higher layers to mention classC now everywhere that classB was typed? Not that doing that would be difficult with refactoring tools, but I was just under the impression that somehow encapsulation would prevent the need for the higher layer to ever even need to mention a lower layer object anywhere.

Comment: If your ClassC also implements the interface and you do not need to call methods not defined in the interface you do not need to edit any code, you can just pass a ClassC like you would a ClassB

Comment: Sorry @VictorS it seems I'm lacking an understanding of something very simple somewhere. Let's say going by the 2) example, the ISomeInterface instance is passed via the constructor to ClassA. Indeed in this example ClassA need not worry about any lower object. But doesn't whoever is responsible for instantiating ClassA need to actually type something like new ClassA(new classB()) and must now have its code edited if the name of ClassB changes to ClassC? What is this mysterious object that instantiates ClassA exactly that allows ClassA to not need to actually type "ClassB" anywhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103554/discussion-between-victor-s-and-user4779).

Comment: I've voting to close this question as "*Needs more focus*". It jumps all over the place from encapsulation to interfaces to separation of concerns to avoidance of coupling leaving it really unclear what's actually being asked (as evidenced by three answers that effectively answer three separate questions).

Comment: I don't think this question is actually about encapsulation? It seems to be more about dependency inversion.

Comment: You shift the responsibility of coupling ClassA to ClassB from ClassA to a manager class which knows when to couple which classes.

Comment: "Passing the buck" is also call dependency injection (q.v.) or inversion of control (q.v.).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

---

### Coupling

> `ClassA` relies upon the interface only, delegating this responsibility of passing the `classB` object elsewhere

This is the idea. If you are separating `ClassA` from `ClassB` by the use of an interface `ISomeInterface`...

> ensuring (`ClassA`) doesn't know `ClassB`

Then you do not want `ClassA` to instantiate `ClassB`. Instead it must recieve an object typed by the interface (for example, it can be received in the constructor).

How does this help encapsulation? You do not get encapsulation for free. However, given that `ClassA` will only use `ClassB` via its interface, you should define interfaces which are sufficient for that use. Ideally you would also remove any part of the interface that is not used. Then you will know exactly what `ClassB` needs to expose. *You still need to design a good interface.*

> however all it does is "pass the buck" elsewhere since someone, somewhere, must instantiate an implementation of ISomeInterface (such as `ClassB`) and pass it as an object to `ClassA`.

Yes.

> It has to happen somewhere. And is the thing that does this now coupling itself to both `ClassA` & `ClassB`?

Yes.

Coupling is unavoidable. You are not trying to make it zero. You are trying to keep it low. Think of it as a cost you have to pay... too much coupling means that maintenance is hard. However, maintenance will never be a zero effort task.

---

### Factories

*I will continue on the assumption that we do dependency injection on the constructor.*

You want to have a **single source of truth** of how to get a `ClassA` object. That is, you do not want to call the constructor passing an object of `ClassB` every time. You want to encapsulate that and reuse it.

If in the future you need to replace `ClassB` by `ClassC`, then there will be a single place where to change that. If there is some logic that picks `ClassB` or `ClassC`, there is a single place where that logic will be. If the instances need to be pooled, you can do that there too.

Thus, you will have a piece of code that has as responsibility to give you an object of `ClassA` bound with the correct implementation of `ISomeInterface`. *And that is the only responsibility of that code.* We could refer to that piece of code as a factory.

**Note**: Creating a factory for each class should not be a goal. You only need the ones you need.

---

Depending on what you are doing, it could make sense that in some places you want `ClassA` created with `ClassB` and in others you want `ClassA` created with `ClassC`. In fact, this could depend on external input.

For another example, let us say we have a video game, where there are some characters. Sometimes they are controlled by the local user, sometimes they are controlled by a player connected through the network, sometimes they are controlled by AI. In this case, we would have three valid implementations, and they could all co-exist.

For another example, it could be that we have a video game that can save progress to local storage, or to a cloud service that allows you to continue playing on a different machine. That is, we have two implementations to save progress, and which one we use depends on user input.

---

### Where to put factories?

Yes, you can apply complex patterns to handle your factories. In fact, I'm saying the factory is *a piece of code* to keep it vague. However, let me point this out: If you are making a library... unless your goal is to make a library dedicated to factory patterns, let the developer of the application decide what factory patterns to use, by not providing any.

Exactly where you want to put your factory code will depend on what kind of application you have. For simple console and desktop projects, you can do all the dependency injecting in `main`. If you are doing something more complex (a network server, for example), you might want some factory solution. Usually, you want to use it after deciding what code will handle input, and after the dependency injection is done, the code does not need to know what factory solution you used.

By factory solution I mean service locators, IoC containers… factory methods, abstract factories… all that stuff. Whatever patterns you pick. *If you pick a library that does it… guess what? It is a dependency! Muahahaha.* So, yeah, after the dependency injection is done, you do not want any code to be aware of it.

---

### Architecture

Abstracting things away is good™. In fact, it happens naturally by the single responsibility principle. *By the way, I think you mean “single responsibility principle” instead of separation of concerns.*

I believe that when they tell you that a layer can only interact with lower layers via an interface, they not abstract interface types, but an interface as in API.

---

However, we could be mixing all the layer talk with the concept of abstracting external systems…

The software engineer needs to make an executive decision about the scope of the project, which decides what is part of the system and what is external.

Draw a line. An architectural line. On the left of the line you code that deals with external systems. Which includes writing adapters which abstract the external system. That code must be interchangeable, allowing you to easily swap it in the future if needs be.

**Note**: I am not suggesting to wrap every dependency in adapters. Only external systems. So, no, I'm saying that you need to make an adapter for every library you use, nor the ridiculous idea of isolating from the runtime. While it is true that those would have their own reasons to change, you follow the single responsibility principle and that is enough. This is about external systems as in IO. *Also, I'm saying that you decide what is external.*

Therefore, you do not want the code on the right to depend on code on the left (which could have to change because of external reasons). However, the code on the left can depend on code on the right (which is under your control).

Thus, you will have the adapters (which are on the left) implement an interface (that exists on the right), and the rest of the code on the right of the architectural line will depend on the interface only…

However, somebody has to instantiate the adapter. Where does that code go? It goes to the left of the architectural line. Because, remember, the code to the right cannot depend on the code on the left. Thus the code that instantiates the adapter (which is to the left), must be to the left.

Now, surprise: the operating system is an external system. `main` is a method that handles an event from the operating system (namely the start of the program). And since the operating system is external, `main` goes on the left of the line, and thus it can instantiate the adapters, and it can call code on the right. Well, actually it would call the factory.

Similarly, if you have a form and event handlers the event handlers are on the left. Or if you have web server, the router is on the left. You want that code (`main`, event handlers, router) to call the factory, inject the dependencies, and let the execution flow to the right.

On the flip side. Your code on the right might want to call the external systems. Remember that this is possible via the interfaces. I want to point out that there is another way to do this. Since the flow of execution starts on the left, it is often possible to let the right return, then the left can execute more code.

---

What I’m describing here? The idea of the architectural line comes from Clean Code.

I am taking inspiration from the idea of “functional core, imperative shell”: pure functions can only call pure functions. However impure functions can call pure and impure functions (pure to the right, impure to the left).

Bonus chatter: You might be aware that `async` code has a tendency to propagate. Because `async` methods can call synchronous methods and `await` other `async`  methods. However synchronous cannot await `async` methods. However, you can use the architectural line to keep it on the left (synchronous to the right, `async` to the left).

---

Why do I say left and right instead of talking of higher and lower layers? Because I would treat both the database and the user interface as external systems. However, classic tier architecture will say that the database is a lower layer and the UI is a higher layer.

Also, the communication between internal layers does not have to be held to the same standards. Providing a concrete facade or allowing a “higher” layer to instantiate types of the lower one is acceptable inside the system. *Although, sometimes you want to draw more lines.*

Comment: I'm sorry if I broke etiquette here making this the accepted answer after Doc Brown's very helpful answer, but this answer here so succinctly and beautifully explained everything at a deep level and is extremely helpful for me, thank you. The idea of delegating things to a factory that has the single responsibility of returning this desired interface implementation is exactly the answer to my question, and the added discussion and theory about why this is done was very helpful for further study.

Comment: @user4779 nonsense! My answer came later, and there is nothing wrong with changing the accepted answer. Also, I do not think my answer is succint at all.

Comment: @user4779: there is no etiquette here which forbids changing an accepted answer afterwards, I am fine with this.

Comment: "*How does this help encapsulation? Simple. ClassB is a detail as far as ClassA is concerned.*" That isn't encapsulation; that is abstraction, ie decoupling.

Comment: This answer would be better if the paragraph that begins "Exactly where you want to put your factory code..." and the one after it were more emphasized. Those two paragraphs directly answer the question; the rest is background.

Comment: The "thing that does this" doesn't necessarily introduce coupling; for example, it's entirely ordinary to define a method to return a `List<Foo>` without specifying what concrete type of list.

Answer (score 22):

Your confusion is probably caused by focusing on meaningless class and interface names, with no real usage scenario behind it. So better let us make a concrete example (I prefer C#, but it is not really different in other languages like Java).

The `IComparable` interface in the .NET framework looks (simplified) like this:

```cs
interface IComparable
{
  int CompareTo (object obj); 
}
```

The interface belongs to the `System` assembly.

There are classes like `ArrayList` (also part of the .NET Framework, inside `System.Collections`) which provide some functionality for objects implementing this interface, foremost `Sort`. `ArrayList` corresponds to your `ClassA`.

So obviously, since these classes were written years ago, they don't know anything about classes which are newly created today.

Now you write a new program with a class `Balloon` which implements `IComparable` (for example, by comparing balloons by their volume). This is `ClassB` in your question. So there is your program which

- creates one instance of `ArrayList` and several instances of `Balloon` objects
- puts the `Balloon` objects into `ArrayList`
- and calls the `Sort` method, which just works, though it has never seen your `Balloon` class before.

So yes, the "buck" of deriving and instantiating a class B is passed to someone else - to the code utilizing the interface and the existing class A - and this makes perfectly sense.

A final note: many questions about interfaces, the strategy pattern, the template method pattern or the Open-Closed-principle can be more easily understood when one thinks in terms of separated libraries, where one lib is provided by a 3rd party vendor and cannot be changed easily by a user of that lib.

Comment: The note about libraries is very useful. If library is too flexible, in encapsulates nothing, if library is very specific, it can't be reused. This greatly illustrates degree of encapsulation.

Comment: You've provided an answer to something. But is it to the question? The title is asking about encapsulation. The question then talks about separation of concerns. Then it introduces interfaces and finally talks of coupling and dependency inversion. Your answer has been accepted, so presumably it says what the OP wanted to hear. But it doesn't begin to address @user4779's confusion over all of these terms and risks leaving them thinking they've got their meanings clear in their head, which they most certainly haven't.

Comment: @Basilevs, you are using a strange definition of encapsulation. Encapsulation is another term for data hiding, ie it has absolutely nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @DavidArno thanks, I thought I was going mad. People seem to invent their own definitions for encapsulation and they rarely mean the same thing. I think that's because in practice few people actually apply the concept of encapsulation any more in a world of anaemic domain models and procedural "service layers."

Comment: @DavidArno: I think most of the confusion the OP has comes from sticking to abstract, meaningless class names instead of trying to look at some real-world examples. And my answer is not the accepted one (without the comments, I would not have even noticed that the OP accepted mine temporarily).

Comment: @AntP, "*I think that's because in practice few people actually apply the concept of encapsulation any more in a world of anaemic domain models and procedural "service layers."*" On this point we completely disagree. Encapsulation is orthogonal to OO (or any other paradigm). Closures for example also provide encapsulation.

Comment: @DavidArno yes that's a fair point - I suppose I am just using this as an opportunity to gripe about the lack of application of "tell, don't ask" in modern OO code, to the extent where you actually get funny looks for trying to apply it. Maybe the only real solution is for OOP to go away entirely.

Comment: @DavidArno encapsulation hides information, design decisions about a component internals is such information. Smaller API surface reveals less information about component, and is therefore an instrument of encapsulation. Abstraction is a subset of encapsulation and can be used interchangeably in this context.

Comment: @Basilevs, "*Abstraction is a subset of encapsulation and can be used interchangeably in this context*". No. [Please see this answer to an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742527/7122). It clearly explains the difference between the two terms.

Comment: @Basilevs, in short, the difference can be summed up as "*encapsulation is concrete; abstraction is abstract!*"

Comment: @DavidArno narrow definition of encapsulation was obsolete when setters fell out of fashion:)

Answer (score 0):

This is severely overthought. Look into how Go does it, as an example.  That approach removes all the unnecessary cruft.  Too much stuff has stacked up around this idea over the years, and most of these ideas can be torched.

- An interface is nothing more than a promise about which methods are guaranteed to exist; so that the compiler can reject a method call that will fail to exist.  In some languages you must declare that you implement the interface on the class.  In other languages, such as Go, if you pass in a struct that HAS the interface methods, then it's valid to assign the struct to that interface type. This choice means that you can declare one or two method interfaces, and pass in legacy structs that you don't want to modify.
- In Go, you just have structures.  They can have methods attached to them.  You can make some members private and others public; but that's kind of unnecessary, and sometimes counter-productive when you need to get in and fix something.  If you just use structs with all public members, you can hide which struct it is (and therefore all struct members) by just assigning the struct to an interface with the minimum number of methods you actually need.

Trying to encapsulate data structures themselves is extremely counter-productive when these structures need to match an on-disk or on-network data structure.

If you want to keep code "encapsulated", then recognize that you are passing in a struct that might define a dozen methods, but you only need one or two of them for the task at hand.  So just create an interface with those two methods.  Now you are only coupled to those two methods bound to a reference.

If you think about something like Java IO classes and interfaces, they often have interfaces that just have way too many methods on them; and it's inconvenient because you need to modify the class to declare the interface.  It's much better for a third-party library library to come along and just make its own interface and assign your struct instance to it.

Comment: Isn't this what happens in C# with ISomeInterface obj = new ClassB(); ?

Comment: in Java/C#, you must mark classes as actually implementing interfaces.  In Go, you could import an entire codebase that is built on type struct that has all the members; and it might be the client defining all the interfaces.  "io.Reader" interface only requires "Write([]byte) (int,error)".   In Go, if you assign to an interface that demands this Write method, if the struct has that Write method, then fine.  The point of the interface is that the compiler knows what methods can be called.

You really get a hard time from other Go programs if you have more than 4 or 5 methods in an interface.